# How to sign BoxContentSDK.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, sign

I used Carthage to build the BoxContentSDK.framework. Everything runs in the simulator and on device. When I go to submit to the app store, I get the error that the BoxContentSDK.framework is not signed. The framework is added in the embed frameworks section of the project and code sign on copy is set. The logs say: BoxContentSDK.framework: replacing existing signature, then BoxContentSDK.framework: code object is not signed at all

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You need to do additional work besides just adding the framework. The BOX SDK page links to the wrong page. Here is the correct page:
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/5fd867c4895b4f59d70181dec169a1644f4430e3/README.md#if-youre-building-for-ios